# Нужна ли запятая перед "чем"

Tags: пунктуация

Брат Январь хотел быть раньше(,) чем Декабрь. Дружнее(,) чем раньше.

Answer (score 3):

*Брат Январь хотел быть раньше, чем Декабрь. Дружнее, чем раньше.* По-моему, явные сравнительные обороты, запятая нужна в обоих случаях. В первом случае есть трудность: если бы речь шла не о героях сказки, а о месяцах реальных - как о времени, возможно, было бы без запятой: месяц был не раньше чем декабрь - можно заменить на "не раньше декабря", значит, это оборот. Здесь же идёт сравнение времени пребывания героев, запятая нужна. Можно проверить так: *Брат Январь хотел быть раньше, чем был Декабрь* - сравнительные придаточные, запятая нужна.